# How to retrive third level's data from firebase databse in web

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Here is my firebase-database structure

[firebase database structure image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jy9sffbkg0J-Pm70p0cVjWm7bmB-adE0)

At first, I tried

```
const messages_ref = database.ref('messages/'+currentCommonSpace.value+'/');
    messages_ref.on('value', gotoData, gotoError);

    function gotoData(message_data) {

        var message_key = message_data.key;
        console.log('keys:'+message_key);

        var message_val = message_data.val();
        console.log('val:'+message_val);
    }

    function gotoError() {
        console.log('error occur');
    }
```

This functions output:

keys: messages

val:[object Object]

Second:

```
function gotoData(message_data) {
       message_data.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
           childSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot2){

               var list_key = childSnapshot2.key;
               console.log('keys:'+list_key);
               var list_val = childSnapshot2.val().data;
               console.log('val:'+list_val);
           });
       });
   }
```

Output: 
keys: all the keys of leaf node data is showing. 
Val: For any event, it shows all of the data including previously inserted but here should be shown only newly added/changed data.

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu (⠇) of [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Here is the firebase database JSON tree file you wanted, 
[ https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xVGiyAkOdWCtQE-kyKYy5z4NJjEkxRKZ  ]

In the leaf node data: "manually formatted JSON string", I knew It could be multiple nodes but I was testing for a single leaf node.